# Silverlight and reporting

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008

In a reporting application based on Silverlight 4 could we use at the same time Silverlight for charting and a reporting tool (Crystal reports or SSRS) for tabular formating hence there's no ReportViewer in Silverlight 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Silverlight Viewer for SSRS by PerpetuumSoft:
http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Downloads.aspx?lang=en&pid=116